# pass a value from input boxes from one page to another page while storing the data in eloqua through action script

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, form-submit

I want to pass a value from input boxes from one page to another page either through javascript or jquery while storing the data in eloqua through action script

the script is hosted on the below page:

http://info.cvent.com/?elqPURLPage=63

it' working fine but the value in TY_URL is showing alert twice but i defined it only one time.

Comment: Hi I am not aware about SessionStorage, It works on HTML 5 and most of the browsers like IE 7 and IE 8 doesn't support this at all. I really appreciate if you will help me on that validate function why ty_url is popping the alert twice..I would like to know what went wrong with my validate function??

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessionStorage to store the variable values